# ADsPath and spaces in an OU

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I'm using `GetObject()` with an `LDAP://` ADsPath in a script for adding users to groups.

However, when a group has a space in its name, like "Student Groups", `GetObject()` cannot find it.

I have tested it with another group with no spaces and it works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this issue.

```
groupPath = "LDAP://cn=EY2014,ou=Student Groups,ou=Groups,dc=Domain,dc=com"
Set group = GetObject(groupPath)
```

Error: 
There is no such object on the server, code 80072030, source (null)

entire code:

```
dim groupPath
dim userPath
dim member

'groups the script with join the user to 
groupPath = "LDAP://cn=EY2014,ou=Student Groups,ou=Groups,cn=B**r Sc***l,dc=B****r,dc=surrey,dc=sch,dc=uk"

'links to the name box at start of script 
userPath = "LDAP://cn=" & strUserName & ",cn=users,dc=B*r,dc=s***y,dc=sch,dc=uk"

addToGroup userPath,groupPath

sub addToGroup(userPath, groupPath)
    dim objGroup
    set objGroup = getobject(groupPath)

    for each member in objGroup.members
        if lcase(member.adspath) = lcase(userPath) then
            exit sub
        end if
    next
    objGroup.Add(userPath)

end sub
```

Comment: You need to escape the space, however you do that in LDAP DNs.

Comment: what does that mean sorry??

Comment: Are you using that path with `GetObject()` or something else? Also, what is the exact error message, if any?

Comment: its just saying the object doesn't exist when it does, as I said when I use another group without spaces in the name it works fine and yes I am using get object

Comment: Your sample ADs path was wrong (`cn` instead of `ou`), are you really sure you're using a correct path?

Comment: ive just made those changes and it still have there is no  such object on the server...

Comment: im sure its because the our "Student Groups" has a space in it

Comment: @James I can guarantee you that a space in the distinguished Name does not cause the problem you described. Please post the exact code you currently have (you may obfuscate the domain name as per RFC2606) as well as the exact error message includig the error number. Also compare your distinguished name to the actual attribute of the AD object (enable *View > Advanced Features* in AD Users and Computers and verify the value in the *Attribute Editor* tab of the object's properties).

Comment: @EJP No, you don't need to escape spaces in distinguished names for this.

Comment: I have put the whole code above along with the error message

Comment: `cn=B**r Sc***l` should probably be `ou=B**r Sc***l`. Please verify the destinguished name as described in my previous comment.

Comment: the error is gone now but it hasent added the user to the group

Comment: Did you refresh the view before checking the members of the group?

Comment: I did but if I press refresh two times it appears to work! Thankyou for your help guys... I feel so stupid haha